# When the base change functor of modules is full?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, derived-functors, flatness

Let $\varphi: A \longrightarrow B$ be a morphism of $k$-algebras (with identity and not necessarily commutative) and $k$ a commutative ring (with identity). Let $F:= {}_B B_A \otimes_A {}_A (-) : \mathbf{Mod}_A \longrightarrow \mathbf{Mod}_B$.

**Question)** Are there any characterisations of $k$-algebra morphisms $\varphi: A \rightarrow B$ such that $F$ is full?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** As noticed by Jeremy Rickard, my claim that $\varphi: A \rightarrow B$ being fully faithful implied fullness was completely stupid. Indeed, if $F$ is faithful and full, then $\text{End}_A ({}_A A) \cong A^{op} \cong B^{op} \cong \text{End}_B ({}_B B_A \otimes_A A)$. I've modified, then, the question accordingly.

Comment: I guess you're looking for the characterization of *$k$-algebra morphisms* $\varphi$ rather than of modules.

Comment: @Berci Yes, sure. I was thinking about $B$ as a left $A$-module. I will edit to reinforce it.

Comment: Even for faithfully flat morphisms $\varphi$ of commutative algebras, the functor $F$ is usually not full.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Hmm. Maybe I'm overseeing something trivial. I mean $\mathbf{Mod}_A$ is equivalent to the category of descent data over the covering $A \rightarrow B$. So you're claiming that there are morphisms of $B$-modules such that each of these $B$-modules are of the form $B \otimes_A M_i$ but the morphism between them does not preserve the descent data. I have to think. I'm not sure if that's possible. Do you have some instance in mind?

Comment: Yes. Consider the case where $\varphi$ is the inclusion $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: In fact, for any $\varphi:A\to B$, $\text{Hom}_A(A,A)\to\text{Hom}_B(F(A),F(A))$ will only be an isomorphism if $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. So this is the only case when $F$ is fully faithful.

Comment: @JeremyRickard You're right. I was being silly. Being full is totally orthogonal to being faithful. I will edit the question.